# how to multiple image in laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel

I tried the following code but an error occurs when I run the project

```
$files = $request->file('files');

    if($request->hasFile('files'))
    {
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $path = $file->store('public/gallery');

            ProductGallery::create([
                'products_id' => $product->id,
                'url' => $path
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Upon using hasFile on an array it seems that it only checks the first element from the array. If the first element of your files array is empty, the result will always be false. A workaround to your problem is:

```
    $files = $request->file('files');

    if(count($request->file('files')) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            if ($file->isValid()) {
                /* Write your file upload code here */
            }
        }
    }
```